# Lit component repeat.js console log error TypeError: items is not iterable

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, lit

I am using Lit components library. In my code I fetch data and putting it in a reactive property. Then I am using repeat.js function from Lit to iterate thought that array.
Everything is working but I got an error in console that I want to get rid of.

Here is fetch function:

```
 async getData(){
    try {
        const response = await myFetch(`${baseURL}`, 'GET', '')
        this.myProperty = response.data
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Error) {
        console.log(err.message);
      } else {
        console.log('Unexpected error', err);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here I declare my reactive property:

```
@property() myProperty: any
```

And here the iteration:

```
${repeat(this.myProperty, (item:any) => item.id, (item, index) => html`
          <div>Data</div>
`)}
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: What is that initial value of `myProperty`? Perhaps it fails to render the component before the data arrives? (Just a guess)

Comment: It is an array with objects in it, when I google that error it refer to iteration of objects.  But everything iterates perfectly, it just that error that comes up in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Lesiak pointed out in the comment, you need an initial value for the reactive property, otherwise it would be `undefined` on first render and fail to iterate.

```
@property() myProperty: any[] = [];
```

For extra points of improvement, is `myProperty` something you expect to be set from outside the component, or via an attribute? If so, it would be better to add the type option: (https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#conversion-type)

```
@property({type: Array}) myProperty: any[] = [];
```

If not, using `@state()` decorator would be more relevant: (https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#internal-reactive-state)

```
@state() myProperty: any[] = [];
```